# Prove this : $\left(a\cos\alpha\right)^n + \left(b\sin\alpha\right)^n = p^n$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves

I have this question: 
If the line $x\cos\alpha + y\sin\alpha = p$ touches the curve $\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^\frac{n}{n - 1} + \left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^\frac{n}{n - 1} = 1$

then prove that $\left(a\cos\alpha\right)^n + \left(b\sin\alpha\right)^n = p^n$

I know that the equation given is an equation of the line in normal form with perpendicular distance $p$ from origin.

Also the slope of given line is $-\cot\alpha$

and this slope of line will be equal to the slope of the curve. But equating both is not yielding the desired result.

The only little progress I seem to make after substituting $x$  and $y$ from the equation of line to the equation of curve seems futile to prove this further.

I seem to make no further progress in this question. What should I do?

Comment: Why not use mathematical induction

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I don't think that will take too far and won't be a good method to solve this. However I'm trying that.

Comment: Take base case as $n/n-1=2$ i hope you know why

Comment: @ArchisWelankar yeah you mean curve is a ellipse.

Comment: Ya hope you get it also if n/n-1=1 there exists no such number

Comment: @ArchisWelankar yeah.

Answer (score 3):

Note the slope of the line is
$$ m_1=-\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha} $$
and the slope of the tangent line of the curve at $(x_0,y_0)$ is
$$ m_2=y'|_{x=x_0}=-\frac{b}{a}\left(\frac{bx_0}{ay_0}\right)^{\frac1{n-1}}.$$
Thus from $m_1=m_2$ we have
$$ y_0=\frac{b^n\sin^{n-1}\alpha}{a^n\cos^{n-1}\alpha}x_0.$$
Noting that $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the line, we have
$$ x_0=\frac{pa^n\cos^{n-1}\alpha}{a^n\cos^{n}\alpha+b^n\sin^{n}\alpha}, y_0=\frac{pb^n\sin^{n-1}\alpha}{a^n\cos^{n}\alpha+b^n\sin^{n}\alpha}. $$
But $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the curve, namely
 $\left(\frac{x_0}{a}\right)^\frac{n}{n - 1} + \left(\frac{y_0}{b}\right)^\frac{n}{n - 1} = 1$
from which we deduce
$$\left(a\cos\alpha\right)^n + \left(b\sin\alpha\right)^n = p^n. $$

Comment: While I'm solving this lhs comes out correct but getting stuck in rhs. I think it won't come out correct.