# General algebra doubt

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $$\left(\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n \left(\frac{x_0}{y_0}\right)^\frac{1}{n - 1}$$

Now suppose if I multiply by power $(n - 1)$ to both sides then the equation will look something like this :

$$\left(\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}\right)^\left(n - 1\right) = \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n \left(\frac{x_0}{y_0}\right)$$

Have I committed some mistake here? I'm asking this because I'm confused. Also I'm not getting correct answer of my question. I think I have did all the steps correctly. I just have doubt in this one.

The doubt is whether multiplying by power $(n - 1)$ to both sides then l.h.s is easy but how will the $\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n$ term on r.h.s will be effected.
Kindly point out my mistake.

Comment: you forgot to raise $(b/a)^n$ to the power as well

Comment: @ZachEffman where?

Comment: In the only step you show here

Comment: Also $(\frac{x_0}{y_0})^{(\frac{1}{n-1})^{n-1}} = \frac{x_0}{y_0}$, not what you have

Comment: @ZachEffman I don't think so. Kindly see the steps again.

Comment: @ZachEffman yeah that's wrong. I'm correcting it.

Answer (score 2):

In general $(ab)^n$ = $a^n b^n$ and $(a^n)^m = a^{nm}$. Therefore raising both sides to the power $n-1$ yields

$$\left(\frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}\right)^{n-1} = \left(\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n} \left(\frac{x_0}{y_0}\right)^\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1} =\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n(n-1)} \left(\frac{x_0}{y_0}\right).$$

Comment: <a href="http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1700351/317580">so I think this one's wrong</a>

Comment: @user109256 I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I think this solution has a mistake http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1700351/317580 see the similar steps. He manipulated them wrong.

Comment: @user109256 I don't see a similar manipulation in his answer.

Comment: the step where he equated $m_1 = m_2$

Comment: @user109256 Oh, I see what you're saying. Your mistake is that you are considering $\left(\frac{x_0}{y_0}\right)^\frac{1}{n-1}$ instead of $\left(\frac{bx_0}{ay_0}\right)^\frac{1}{n-1}$.